# Написать функцию определения типа треугольника

Tags: vba

Пользователь вводит три числа и программа показывает окно, что каким треугольник может быть с вводимыми сторонами: равнобедренный, прямоугольный, равносторонний или же его вообще не существует.

```
Sub tri()
Dim a, b, c As Integer
If a = b Then
MsgBox ("равнобедренный")
End If
If a And b Then
MsgBox ("Прямоугольник")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Как я понял, тебе нужно ввести 3 числа, и программа должна определить какого типа может быть треугольник с введенными сторонами?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT в точку, именно это и должен сделать софт

Comment: Подразумевался не прямоугольник, а треугольник с прямым углом? Нужна функция (Function) или процедура (Sub)

Comment: @vikttur макро функция

Comment: А если он равнобедренный и прямоугольный - что должно выводиться? (знаю, знаю - в целых, даже рациональных, числах - невозможно)

Comment: @Igor и то и то

Comment: @Igor что - невозможно ?

Comment: @coder - у Вас стороны - целые числа. Треугольник со такими сторонами не может быть одновременно прямоугольным и равнобедренным.

Comment: И да, соглашусь с Игорем, не существует равнобедренного прямоугольного треугольника с целыми числами...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ячейку вписать формулу:

```
=tri(A1:C1)
```

где *A1:C1* - диапазон ячеек

Код в общий модуль:

```
Function tri(Rng As Range) As String
Dim sStr As String
Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long
    If Rng.Cells.Count <> 3 Then tri = "значений<>3": Exit Function
    a = Rng(1).Value
    b = Rng(2).Value
    c = Rng(3).Value

    ' a=0 - обходим ошибку при a=b=c=0
    If a = 0 Or a + b < c Or a + c < b Or b + c < a Then
        sStr = "не существует"
    Else
        If a = b And a = c Then
            sStr = "равносторонний"
        Else
            If a = b Or a = c Or b = c Then
                sStr = "равнобедренный"
            Else
                If a ^ 2  = b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 Or _
                        b ^ 2 = a ^ 2 + c ^ 2 Or _
                        c ^ 2 = b ^ 2 + a ^ 2 Then
                    sStr = "прямоугольный"
                Else
                    sStr = "разносторонний"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    tri = sStr
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам алгоритм действий:

1. Пользователь ввел 3 числа;
2. Создаем первое условие: **если** `( (a < c + b) и (b < a + c) и (c < a + b) )` **тогда** треугольник существует
3. Внутри первого условия создаем вложенные условия где будем узнавать тип треугольника:

   3.1 **если** `( (a == b) и ( a == c ) и (c == b) )` **тогда**: *Треугольник равносторонний*

   3.2 **если**`( (a == b) или ( a == c ) или (c == b) )` **тогда**: *Треугольник равнобедренный*

   3.3 **если** `( (c^2 == a^2 + b^2 ) или (b^2 == a^2 + c^2) или (b^2 == c^2 +a^2) )` **тогда**: *Треугольник прямоугольный*

   3.4 **если** `( ( (a == b) или ( a == c ) или (c == b) ) и ( (c^2 == a^2 + b^2 ) или (b^2 == a^2 + c^2) или (b^2 == c^2 +a^2) ) )` **тогда**: *Треугольник равнобедренный прямоугольный*
4. Добавляем к ПЕРВОМУ условию **иначе**: *Треугольник не существует*

Comment: подчеркнул эту строку 
`if ((c^2 = a^2 + b^2 ) Or (b^2 = a^2 + c^2) or (b^2 = c^2 +a^2) )Then`
и эту
`If (( a = b or ( a = c ) or (c = b) ) and ( (c^2 = a^2 + b^2 ) or (b^2 = a^2 + c^2) or (b^2 = c^2 +a^2) ) )then`

Comment: Проверил в редакторе - не подчеркивает, не закрашивает, не ругается

Comment: Замечание: если предварительно отсортировать введенные числа по возрастанию (ну или по убыванию), то условия для проверок заметно упростятся. :)